# Which files to install bootstrap 4 locally on(windows ) for a web application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add Bootstrap-4 to my project without a cdn by installing it locally in my project can anyone send me a template of such project i work on windows

I've tried to add **jquery** and **popper** but wasn't able to add the files properly(I think the path is correct).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I just want a fully functional bootstrap 4 page

Comment: Check out: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/#compiled-css-and-js

Answer (score 0):

Download the bootstrap.css and link it in index.html under head tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="*relative path to bootstrap css*">
```

Comment: yes finnaly  i add to add also popper and jquery files(it is working i did it before reading your answer thanks for all (^.^)